# Can you set EncryptionLevel programmatically for Merge Replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, replication

I'm creating a subscription programmatically using RMO which works nicely.

Can you set EncryptionLevel programmatically for Merge Replication, as from WinForms it failes saying that SSL needs to be set (but doesn't when it's ASP.NET).

Comment: It's not clear what relevance WinForms and ASP.Net have to a question that seems to be about replication.

Comment: Yeah, thats why I was confused. My asp.net app using a DLL worked while a winform app using the SAME DLL didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not seem like that, the `MergePublication` class does not expose any `EncryptionLevel` property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.replication.mergepublication.aspx